# Security of Unity Rpc calls

Tags: unity

Im just starting to code my game in unity and have been reading up that rpc calls are not validated and can run havoc on the server. For example a modified client can connect to your server and just disconnect everyone by sending:

networkView.RPC("disconnecteverybody", RPCMode.All);

[RPC] void disconnecteverybody () { 
Network.Disconnect();
}

Is there a way to validate packets?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/500386/security-and-rpcs.html